# Significance of adding zero rows and columns to a matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose I have a $n\times n$ matrix to which I add a row of zeros and a column of zeros, somewhere in the matrix, to make it $(n+1)\times (n+1)$. When I multiply the matrix by itself, or multiply it with other matrices where I have inserted a row and column of zeros in the same way, it seems to behave as though the extra row/column were not there. Is there a way to think about the added row/column, and why it does not affect the product? What have I done to this matrix? I think (but not sure at all) that it is like I have put my matrix in a higher matrix space but it only spans the subset where it previously existed?

Comment: When you say "somewhere" in the matrix, what do you mean? Some ways of inserting rows and columns of zeros get results different from what you describe, so I suspect you have some extra rules that you are following that you have not described.

Comment: @DavidK i thought that the placement of the null row/column is irrelevant?

Comment: If you put the nulls in row $k$ and column $m$ where $k=m$ then I think it works out as you say. If $k\neq m$ then you may get different results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's like being confined to a plane. The vectors all have length $2$. When you add a row of $0$s, you add a $\color{red}{null}$ space. The inhabitants of the plane can't see any change because the addition is a $\color{red}{null}$ space.

---

**No null spaces**
$$
\mathbf{A} =
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\in\mathbb{C}^{2\times2}_{2}
$$
Life is good. The linear system 
$$
 \mathbf{A} x = b
$$
*always* has a *unique solution*
$$
 x = b
$$
**Add a null space**

Add a row of $0$s.
$$
\mathbf{A} =
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\in\mathbb{C}^{3\times2}_{2}
$$
Life isn't so good. We have solvability conditions based on the subspace decomposition of the data
$$
b =
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 b_{1} \\
 b_{2} \\
 b_{3} \\
\end{array}
\right)
=
\color{blue}{b_{\mathcal{R}}} + 
\color{red}{b_{\mathcal{N}}}
=
\color{blue}{\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 b_{1} \\
 b_{2} \\
 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)}
+
\color{red}{\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 0 \\
 0 \\
 b_{3} \\
\end{array}
\right)}
$$

1. If $b_{1} = b_{2} = 0$, there is *no solution.*
2. If $b_{1} \ne 0$, or $b_{2} \ne 0$, and $b_{3} = 0$ a *unique solution* exists.
3. If $b_{1} \ne 0$, or $b_{2} \ne 0$, and $b_{3} = 0$ there are an *infinite number of solutions.*

---

**Fundamental Theorem of Linear Algebra**

The four fundamental subspaces for an arbitrary matrix $\mathbf{A}\in\mathbb{C}^{m\times n}_{\rho}$ can be expressed as
$$
\begin{align}
%
  \mathbf{C}^{n} = 
    \color{blue}{\mathcal{R} \left( \mathbf{A}^{*} \right)} \oplus
    \color{red}{\mathcal{N} \left( \mathbf{A} \right)} \\
%
  \mathbf{C}^{m} = 
    \color{blue}{\mathcal{R} \left( \mathbf{A} \right)} \oplus
    \color{red} {\mathcal{N} \left( \mathbf{A}^{*} \right)}
%
\end{align}
$$
The game you are playing involves one of these two themes:
$$
  \mathbf{C}^{n} = 
    \color{blue}{\mathcal{R} \left( \mathbf{A}^{*} \right)} 
    \quad \Rightarrow \quad 
  \mathbf{C}^{n} = 
    \color{blue}{\mathcal{R} \left( \mathbf{A}^{*} \right)} \oplus
    \color{red}{\mathcal{N} \left( \mathbf{A} \right)} \\
$$
or
$$
  \mathbf{C}^{m} = 
    \color{blue}{\mathcal{R} \left( \mathbf{A} \right)} 
    \quad \Rightarrow \quad 
    \mathbf{C}^{m} =
      \color{blue}{\mathcal{R} \left( \mathbf{A} \right)} \oplus
      \color{red}{\mathcal{N} \left( \mathbf{A}^{*} \right)} \\
$$

---

Explore MSE

Existence and uniqueness in terms of the null spaces: 
[Why does $A^{T}Ax=A^{T}b have infinitely many solution algebraically when A has dependent columns?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2262225/why-does-atax-atb-have-infinitely-many-solution-algebraically-when-a-has/2262432#2262432,)

[Exact solution of overdetermined linear system](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2244851/exact-solution-of-overdetermined-linear-system/2261603#2261603)

Adding the null spaces and seeing how life changes:[Pseudo-inverse of a matrix that is neither fat nor tall?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1971211/pseudo-inverse-of-a-matrix-that-is-neither-fat-nor-tall/2181445#2181445)